# VBA Excel- Worksheet_calc defining variable value of cell that has an equation, mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare the value of the cells in X1 through X5 to something. I.e. If X4 = "buy" and X3 <= -130 then execute code.

I keep getting a mismatch type error though. The cells in the spreadsheet contain equations (like vlookup) to obtain their value.

I did this in Worksheet_calculate because I need it update when the X cells change (which is like every second)

Any help for this newbie would be very much appreciated!!

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  'On Error Resume Next
'Sheets("Basic Orders").Unprotect Password:="password"
 Dim dir As String
 Dim unpl As Integer
 Dim pl As Integer
 Dim loss As Integer
 Dim possize As Integer
 Dim notrade As Boolean
 Dim ExpirationDate As String
 Dim NameExists As Boolean
 Dim LastRow As Long
 dir = Range("X4").value
unpl = Range("X3").value
 pl = Range("X2").value
loss = Range("X5").value
possize = Range("X1").value



If dir = "BUY" And unpl <= -130 And possize <> 0 Then   'stop loss of 130 dollars
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).value = "EUR"
Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).value = "CASH"
Cells(LastRow + 1, 8).value = "IDEALPRO"
Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).value = "USD"
Cells(LastRow + 1, 13).value = "SELL"
Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).value = possize
Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).value = "MKT"
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select
Call OrderFunctions.order2(Selection.rows, serverCell, extAttribColumn, True)
ActiveCell.offset(0, 25).value = Time
ActiveCell.offset(0, 25).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
```

Comment: What line is your error occurring on?

Comment: It is occurring on possize = Range("X1").value

Comment: And what is in X1? A text entry will cause the error you have mentioned - as your code is expecting an Integer.

Comment: X1 =ABS(SUMIF(AA11:AA90,"BUY",U10:U90)-SUMIF(AA11:AA90,"SELL",U10:U90))  where the sum is of numbers

Comment: What happens if at the front of you code you enter `Application.EnableEvents = False` and at the end `Application.EnableEvents = True`? Which should let the code run to completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, in my X1 sum equation the column u10:u90 would go between numbers and text.

So I just filtered it out for the numbers only and it works. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Type mismatch refers to the value being put into the variable being the wrong type. As an example, the output of your formula in X1 may be a string, instead of the required Integer type.

You can test the content of cell X1

```
var=Range("X1")
Stop
```

Hold your mouse over "var" and it should show the content of the variable. If it's a number  quotes, it is a string and can't be used as is.

```
var=Val(Range("X1"))
```

will give you a numerical output, even if X1 contains a string.

Comment: hmm Ok thanks, I checked the val with the mouseover and it shows = 0 so its not a string, I think there might be a loop somewhere.. Because if I try to type a new line"test =  the cursor moves back to the equals and voids what i type